# No puedo agregar una una columna que sea llave foránea, migracion laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

estoy intentando añadir una columna a una tabla ya existente para hacer referencia a la columna id de mi tabla "sites", sin embargo, obtengo el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`google-places-ranking`.`#sql-4670_53`, CONSTRAINT
> `location_group_place_site_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`)
> REFERENCES `sites` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `location_group_place`
> add constraint `location_group_place_site_id_foreign` foreign key
> (`site_id`) references `sites` (`id`))

este es el código de mi migración

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('location_group_place', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('site_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('site_id')->references('id')->on('sites');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('location_group_place', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('site_id');
    });
}
```

No logro entender cuál es el problema, la misma tabla en otra migración está hecha de la misma manera haciendo referencias a otras tablas, pero cuando quiero añadir esta columna obtengo ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La tabla **location_group_place** esta vacia? prueba agregando nullable o vaciala primero

```
$table->bigInteger('site_id')->unsigned())->nullable();
```

Comment: Gracias! se me había escapado ese dato